# SQLite 3, using unixEpoch and optimise time condition

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

I got about 15 days of data from I would like to query the last 5 days. I would also like to work with epochTime in my conditions.

Here is what I'm using right now :

- To get x values every 200 rows, very fast method by working with rowid only.

  ```
  connection = sql.connect("/home/pi/data.db")
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT epochTime,x from (select rowid,epochTime,x from table1 where (rowid % 200 = 0)) order by rowid ASC")
  x = cursor.fetchall()
  ```
- First try using classic timestamp, however I'm suprised this is taking way more time than soluce 1 (about +2 seconds if fetching the 15 days). Am I doing it wrong ?

  ```
  cursor.execute("SELECT timestamp, epochTime, x from (select rowid,epochTime,x from table1 where (rowid % 200 = 0) and timestamp>(select datetime('now','-5 day'))) order by rowid ASC")
  ```
- Finally, a first attempt by using `epochTime` but it's not working:

  ```
  cursor.execute("SELECT epochTime, x from (select rowid,epochTime,x from table1 where (rowid % 200 = 0) and epochTime>(select datetime('now','-68400'))) order by rowid ASC")
  ```

Note: here is how `epochTime` is parsed, I had to add %s100 to work with highcharts, it can maybe causing an issue for sqlite conditions ? :

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
epochTime = now.strftime("%s100")
```

Does working with "time" condition will automatically slowing the request ? 
How should i write this down to work properly with UnixEpoch ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're adding conditions to the `WHERE` clause, and an index is not available, it can cause the database to do a full table scan.  This could explain the slowness in the second and third queries.

Comment: Is it possible to create an index on an existing and living database ?

Comment: AFAIK yes this is possible.  Anyway, you can try it yourself.